# NetBeans platform language and ANTLR lexer

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How to adapt the NetBeans LexerInput to a CharStream of ANTLR. I have the next implementation, but don't work well. I want to add a new language to the NetBeans platform throught ANTLR lexer.

The Lexer emit only EOF, but the token type is ok, i don't understand.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.Interval;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.LexerInput;

/**
 * @author jonny
 */
public class AntlrCharStream implements CharStream {


    private class CharStreamState {
        int index;
        int line;
        int charPositionInLine;
    }

    private int line = 1;
    private int charPositionInLine = 0;
    private LexerInput input;
    private String name;
    private int index = 0;
    private List<CharStreamState> markers;
    private int markDepth = 0;
    private int lastMarker;

    public AntlrCharStream(LexerInput input, String name) {
        this.input = input;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText(Interval intrvl) {
        return input.readText().toString();
    }

    public String substring(int start, int stop) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public int LT(int i) {
        return LA(i);
    }

    public int getLine() {
        return line;
    }

    public void setLine(int line) {
        this.line = line;
    }

    public void setCharPositionInLine(int pos) {
        this.charPositionInLine = pos;
    }

    public int getCharPositionInLine() {
        return charPositionInLine;
    }

    public void consume() {
        int c = input.read();
        index++;
        charPositionInLine++;

        if (c == '\n') {
            line++;
            charPositionInLine = 0;
        }
    }

    public int LA(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return 0; // undefined
        }

        int c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            c = read();
        }
        backup(i);
        return c;
    }

    public int mark() {
        if (markers == null) {
            markers = new ArrayList<CharStreamState>();
            markers.add(null); // depth 0 means no backtracking, leave blank
        }
        markDepth++;
        CharStreamState state = null;
        if (markDepth >= markers.size()) {
            state = new CharStreamState();
            markers.add(state);
        } else {
            state = (CharStreamState) markers.get(markDepth);
        }
        state.index = index;
        state.line = line;
        state.charPositionInLine = charPositionInLine;
        lastMarker = markDepth;

        return markDepth;
    }

    public void rewind() {
        rewind(lastMarker);
    }

    public void rewind(int marker) {
        CharStreamState state = (CharStreamState) markers.get(marker);
        // restore stream state
        seek(state.index);
        line = state.line;
        charPositionInLine = state.charPositionInLine;
        release(marker);
    }

    public void release(int marker) {
        // unwind any other markers made after m and release m
        markDepth = marker;
        // release this marker
        markDepth--;
    }

    public void seek(int index) {
        if (index < this.index) {
            backup(this.index - index);
            this.index = index; // just jump; don't update stream state (line, ...)
            return;
        }

        // seek forward, consume until p hits index
        while (this.index < index) {
            consume();
        }
    }

    public int index() {
        return index;
    }

    public int size() {
        return -1; //unknown...
    }

    public String getSourceName() {
        return name;
    }

    private int read() {
        int result = input.read();
        if (result == LexerInput.EOF) {
            result = CharStream.EOF;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void backup(int count) {
        input.backup(count);
    }
}
```

```
'[@-1,6:6='<EOF>',<1>,2:2]'
'[@-1,7:7='<EOF>',<1>,2:3]'
'[@-1,8:15='<EOF>',<9>,2:4]'
'[@-1,16:16='<EOF>',<1>,2:12]'
'[@-1,17:23='<EOF>',<8>,2:13]'
'[@-1,24:24='<EOF>',<1>,2:20]'
'[@-1,25:25='<EOF>',<2>,2:21]'
'[@-1,26:26='<EOF>',<1>,3:0]'
'[@-1,27:27='<EOF>',<1>,3:1]'
'[@-1,28:28='<EOF>',<1>,3:2]'
'[@-1,29:29='<EOF>',<1>,3:3]'
'[@-1,30:37='<EOF>',<4>,3:4]'
'[@-1,38:38='<EOF>',<1>,3:12]'
'[@-1,39:43='<EOF>',<5>,3:13]'
'[@-1,44:44='<EOF>',<1>,3:18]'
'[@-1,45:48='<EOF>',<9>,3:19]'
'[@-1,49:49='<EOF>',<1>,3:23]'
'[@-1,50:53='<EOF>',<7>,3:24]'
'[@-1,54:54='<EOF>',<1>,3:28]'
'[@-1,55:56='<EOF>',<6>,3:29]'
'[@-1,57:57='<EOF>',<2>,3:31]'
'[@-1,58:57='<EOF>',<-1>,4:32]'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also trying to make a NetBeans plugin using ANTLR 4. Here's what I came up with after modifying the `AntlrCharStream` from [that tutorial](http://wiki.netbeans.org/New_Language_Support_Tutorial_Antlr). It's working for me so far.

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.Interval;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.LexerInput;

public class AntlrCharStream implements CharStream {

    private final LexerInput input;
    private final String name;
    private int index = 0;
    private int markDepth = 0;

    public AntlrCharStream(LexerInput input, String name) {
        this.input = input;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText(Interval interval) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
    }

    @Override
    public void consume() {
        int character = read();
        if (character == EOF) {
            backup(1);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Attempting to consume EOF");
        }
        index++;
    }

    @Override
    public int LA(int lookaheadAmount) {
        if (lookaheadAmount < 0) {
            return lookBack(-lookaheadAmount);
        } else if (lookaheadAmount > 0) {
            return lookAhead(lookaheadAmount);
        } else {
            return 0; //Behaviour is undefined when lookaheadAmount == 0
        }
    }

    private int lookBack(int amount) {
        backup(amount);
        int character = read();
        for (int i = 1; i < amount; i++) {
            read();
        }
        return character;
    }

    private int lookAhead(int amount) {
        int character = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            character = read();
        }
        backup(amount);
        return character;
    }

    @Override
    public int mark() {
        return ++markDepth;
    }

    @Override
    public void release(int marker) {
        // unwind any other markers made after m and release m
        markDepth = marker;
        // release this marker
        markDepth--;
    }

    @Override
    public void seek(int index) {
        if (index < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Invalid index (%s < 0)", index));
        }

        if (index < this.index) {
            backup(this.index - index);
            this.index = index;
            return;
        }

        // seek forward, consume until p hits index
        while (this.index < index) {
            consume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int index() {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Stream size unknown");
    }

    @Override
    public String getSourceName() {
        return name;
    }

    private int read() {
        int result = input.read();
        if (result == LexerInput.EOF) {
            return EOF;
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }

    private void backup(int count) {
        input.backup(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a better implementation for `getText`? Using this causes an exception to be displayed by NetBeans if you enter an unrecognized token. Perhaps something like `return input.readText(0, input.readLength()).toString();`? Using the provided `Interval` parameter causes errors as well since it is sometime outside the range allowed by NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified Daniel's proposed implementation to implement the function getText. I've also modified how the index position is tracked. It's working for me so far but since I'm out of time, it still needs proper testing.

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.Interval;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.LexerInput;

public class AntlrCharStream implements CharStream {

  private final LexerInput input;
  private final String name;
  private int index = 0;
  private int markDepth = 0;

  public AntlrCharStream(LexerInput input, String name) {
    this.input = input;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String getText(Interval interval) {
    int start = interval.a;
    int stop = interval.b;

    if (start < 0 || stop < start) {
      return "";
    }

    final int pos = this.index;
    final int length = interval.length();
    final char[] data = new char[length];

    seek(interval.a);
    int r = 0;
    while (r < length) {
      final int character = read();
      if (character == EOF) {
        break;
      }

      data[r] = (char) character;
      r++;
    }
    seek(pos);

    if (r > 0) {
      return new String(data, 0, r);
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void consume() {
    int character = read();
    if (character == EOF) {
      backup(1);
      throw new IllegalStateException("Attempting to consume EOF");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int LA(int lookaheadAmount) {
    if (lookaheadAmount < 0) {
      return lookBack(-lookaheadAmount);
    } else if (lookaheadAmount > 0) {
      return lookAhead(lookaheadAmount);
    } else {
      return 0; //Behaviour is undefined when lookaheadAmount == 0
    }
  }

  private int lookBack(int amount) {
    backup(amount);
    int character = read();
    for (int i = 1; i < amount; i++) {
      read();
    }
    return character;
  }

  private int lookAhead(int amount) {
    int character = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      character = read();
    }
    backup(amount);
    return character;
  }

  @Override
  public int mark() {
    return ++markDepth;
  }

  @Override
  public void release(int marker) {
    // unwind any other markers made after m and release m
    markDepth = marker;
    // release this marker
    markDepth--;
  }

  @Override
  public void seek(int index) {
    if (index < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Invalid index (%s < 0)", index));
    }

    if (index < this.index) {
      backup(this.index - index);
      return;
    }

    // seek forward, consume until p hits index
    while (this.index < index) {
      consume();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int index() {
    return index;
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return -1; //unknown...
  }

  @Override
  public String getSourceName() {
    return name;
  }

  private int read() {
    int result = input.read();
    index++;

    if (result == LexerInput.EOF) {
      return EOF;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  }

  private void backup(int count) {
    input.backup(count);
    index -= count;
  }
}
```

I've created a gist with the code in: https://gist.github.com/megothss/849fb466a21793956033 just in case anyone wants to contribute improving it.

Answer (score -1):

A google query "antlr netbeans" reveals a number of articles, albeit for v3 not v4. E.g.,
http://wiki.netbeans.org/New_Language_Support_Tutorial_Antlr

Did you run a different query somehow?

Comment: yes, i used this tutorial before ask. My ANTLR token type are ok, but the text is ever <EOF>, and the sequence numbrer -1. I edit the question with more info. If i run the lexer with a common InputStream not problem.